# Correct VLC transcoding codec

Tags: vlc, ffdshow

I'm not 100% sure I am even asking the right question here, but basically I want to wrap a 4k webcam in a transport stream using VLC so that I can use it as an IPTV server or sorts in some additional software.

What I have so far:

```
vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-adev="Audio (2- 00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-aspect-ratio=16\:9 :dshow-chroma=BGR32 :dshow-vcodec=libx265 :dshow-fps=60 :dshow-acodec=mp4a :dshow-ab=96 :dshow-channels=2 :dshow-samplerate=44100 :no-dshow-config :no-dshow-tuner :live-caching=100 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h.264,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:rtp{dst=227.0.0.1,port=8554,mux=ts}
```

With the above `dshow` commands I can get the picture to display perfectly in a local VLC session. With the RTP commands I seem to have successfully streamed the video card in a transport stream to a degree as I can get audio from the stream in a client VLC session.

The bit that seems to be going wrong though is the transcoding. I have printed the log below just for the server VLC session. h.264 does not seem to be a valid codec, nor is mp4v (which cannot be found on my machine).

Any suggestions on how to fix? I'm currently tearing my hair out on this...

```
-- logger module started --
main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
dshow warning: ConnectFilters: No crossBar routes found (incompatible pin types)
stream_out_transcode error: cannot find video encoder (module:any fourcc:h.26). Take a look few lines earlier to see possible reason.
stream_out_transcode error: cannot create video chain
main warning: new sout input failed (sout_input: 04b265d0)
main error: cannot create packetizer output (I420)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 100 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (115683)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 103 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (115431)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (118376)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 106 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (126477)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (114186)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (120540)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (107243)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (112596)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 107 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (124779)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (121605)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (123958)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (129063)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (96295)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 107 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (120359)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (116294)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (118648)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (124053)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 108 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (138024)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (95972)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (102325)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (114289)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (120643)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (128484)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (127838)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (107587)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (109940)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (114095)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (109449)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (117841)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (128195)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (107249)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (109602)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (114131)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (123485)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (122832)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (129186)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (97323)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (99676)
main warning: no more input streams for this mux
-- logger module stopped --
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tuning the following parameters (can be done through VLC command line) as per your network needs:

```
"--network-caching=33", 
"--file-caching=33", 
"--live-caching=33",
"--clock-synchro=0", 
"--clock-jitter=0",
"--h264-fps=60",
"--avcodec-fast",
"--avcodec-threads=1"
```